# Newbie, error: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python-3.5

I insert into the request any url such as http://www.four-nat.com and get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in 
urllib.error.URLError:

I apologize if I am being unclear, I am just starting out!
Here's the code:

import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url=input("go!")

html=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

soup= BeautifulSoup(html,html.parser)

print (soup)

Comment: Did you want to post the rest of the traceback?

Comment: Note that the `requests` module is much easier to work with and usually preferred.

Comment: hi, yes I have been trying to install it or rather activate it in python3, without good results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request as ur

website = '' # your site link
url_link = ur.urlopen(website).read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url_link, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

Comment: Hi, I keep on getting the  error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 5, in <module>
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>

Comment: write soup= BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml') instead of soup= BeautifulSoup(html,html.parser)